# Как в docker-compose настроить перенаправление http-запрос из одного контейнера в другой через nginx?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Есть сеть из 3 контейнеров: nginx, project1 и project2.

```
version: '3.8'
    
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.21.1
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:80:80
      - 127.0.0.1:433:443
    volumes:
      - ./proj1:/var/www/proj1
      - ./proj2:/var/www/proj2
      - ./.docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./.docker/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:rw
      - ./proj1/.docker/nginx/sites-available/proj1.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-available/proj1.conf:ro
      - ./proj2/.docker/nginx/sites-available/proj2.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-available/proj2.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - proj1
      - proj2
    networks:
      - proj-net

  proj1:
    build:
      context: ./proj1/.docker
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./proj1:/var/www/proj1
    networks:
      - proj-net
     

  proj2:
    build:
      context: proj2/.docker
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./proj2:/var/www/proj2
    networks:
      - proj-net

networks:
  proj-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Как можно сконфигурировать docker-compose таким образом, чтоб делая внутри контейнера proj1 запрос curl proj2.localhost он был адресован контейнеру с nginx и далее контейнеру proj2?

Answer (score 0):

Контейнеризация не выполняет функции проксирования. Поэтому ответ на ваш вопрос: никак.

Делайте запрос на сервис, умеющий осуществлять проксирование (Например Nginx) и уже внутри него конфигурируйте [проксирование](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-http-proxying-load-balancing-buffering-and-caching).